# I get error 0x800A03EC when trying Excel.Shapes.AddPicture

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to make a c# windows form program that creat an excel file including datas and images.

When use in my PC, it works perfect. no error. But when I give this to coworker, 
they got an error while using `Excel.Shapes.AddPicture.`

### Exception texts are

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shapes.AddPicture(String Filename, MsoTriState LinkToFile, MsoTriState SaveWithDocument, Single Left, Single Top, Single Width, Single Height)
   at ItemTableValidator_2.Form1.insertItemImage()
   at ItemTableValidator_2.Form1.BTN_START_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

---

I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. and codes are below.

---

```
    private void insertItemImage()
    {

        Excel.Application targetExcel = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook targetWorkbook = targetExcel.Workbooks.Open(targetFileName);
        Excel.Worksheet targetWorksheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets["Item_Chart"];

        int filenameIdx = 5;
        int imageIdx = 4;
        string[] resourceDir = Directory.GetFiles(editDirectory + "\\Icon","*.png");
        List<string> resourceList = new List<string>();
        List<string> nameList = new List<string>();

        foreach (string dir in resourceDir)
        {
            resourceList.Add(Path.GetFileName(dir));
        }


        targetWorksheet.Rows.RowHeight = 100.0f;
        targetWorksheet.Rows[1].RowHeight = 10.0f;

        for (int idx = 0; idx < resourceList.Count; idx++)
        {
            for (int rowIdx = 2; rowIdx <= targetWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; rowIdx++)
            {
                string tmpString = targetWorksheet.Cells[rowIdx, filenameIdx].Value.ToString() + ".png";

                if ( tmpString == resourceList[idx])
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)targetWorksheet.Cells[rowIdx, imageIdx];

                    float Left = (float)((double)oRange.Left);
                    float Top = (float)((double)oRange.Top);
                    targetWorksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(resourceDir[idx], Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Left, Top, 80, 80);
                }
            }

        }
        targetWorkbook.Save();
        targetWorkbook.Close(true);
        targetExcel.Quit();

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(targetExcel);
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is an Excel runtime error.  Find relevant hits by googling "excel shape.addpicture error 1004".

Comment: Thank you. But there is no 1004 error code. What I found was two case. 1. there is no file. 2. true / false option error. but the files exists and I used true / false option correctly. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Convert the last 4 hex digits of 0x800A03EC to decimal.  That is a 1004 error.